# How to split a value in Excel and make it in two lines in Excel when values are seperated by a slash?

Tags: excel

Below is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Value in Excel cell:

Hello/World

Output needed:

Hello
World
```

Currently I use ALT+Enter and remove the slash. What would be the correct formula to handle this situation- I have tried Char(10) formula but doesn't work because of the slash. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the output in one cell with the textwrap on or are then in different cells one on top of the other?

Comment: Do you want the return in the same cells as the input or different cells?  All these questions matter as it will change the methods.

Comment: Different cell is ok

Comment: One cell, two cells?

Comment: One cell. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the `/` to a line break:

First make sure the output cell has Wrap Text enabled.  It is a format property of the cell.

Then use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(10))
```

[image]

---

In different cells:

Put this formula in the first cell, then copy/drag down:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*999+1,999))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(A1),"/",CHAR(10))
```

Once entered, select the column and wrap the text.

[image]